# Vue.js Passing a variable in a loop to another component

Tags: vue.js

As a beginner in Vue.js,I am trying to create a Todo app, but problems seems to passing a variable to another component when looping.
i want to pass item to another embedded component.
Here what I have with all the components:

### in main.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import Todo from "./components/Todo";
import itemComponent from "./components/itemComponent";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.component('todo', Todo);
Vue.component('itemcomponent', itemComponent);

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

### in App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <todo></todo>
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" width="25%" />
  <!--  <HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!" /> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
  

  },
};
</script>
```

### in Todo.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="nameme" />
    <button type="click" @click="assignName">Submit</button>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in result" :key="item.id">
     <itemcomponent {{item}}></itemcomponent>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import { itemcomponent } from "./itemComponent";

export default {
  props:['item'],
  data() {
    return {
      nameme: "",
      upernameme: "",
      result: [],
      components: {
        itemcomponent,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    assignName: function () {
      this.upernameme = this.nameme.toUpperCase();
      this.result.push(this.nameme);
      this.nameme = "";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

### in itemComponent.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value={{item }}/>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  props: {
    item: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```

what is my mistake? thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a bunch of mistakes:

1. You should import single page components inside their parent components and register them there, not in main.js file. EDIT: Explaination to this is given in [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration)

> Global registration often isn’t ideal. For example, if you’re using a build system like Webpack, globally registering all components means that even if you stop using a component, it could still be included in your final build. This unnecessarily increases the amount of JavaScript your users have to download.

2. You have a component registration in Todo.vue, but you have misplaced it inside data so its is just a data object that is not getting used, move into components.
3. In your  loop you have item.id, but your item is just a plain string, it does not have an id property. Either change item to object with `id` property, or simply use the `index` provided in loop (not recommended).
4. Pass your item as a prop, not mustache template. So in Todo.vue replace `{{ item }}` with `:item="item"`
5. In your ItemComponent.vue you have mustache syntax once again in the attribute. Change `value={{item }}` to `:value="item"`

So here's the final code:

main.js

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

in App.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <todo></todo>
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" width="25%" />
  <!--  <HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!" /> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Todo from './components/Todo.vue';

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Todo,
  },
};
</script>
```

in Todo.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="nameme" />
    <button type="click" @click="assignName">Submit</button>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in result" :key="index">
     <itemcomponent :item="item"></itemcomponent>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import { itemcomponent } from "./itemComponent";

export default {
  props:['item'],
  data() {
    return {
      nameme: "",
      upernameme: "",
      result: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    assignName: function () {
      this.upernameme = this.nameme.toUpperCase();
      this.result.push(this.nameme);
      this.nameme = "";
    },
  },
  components: {
    itemComponent,
  }
};
</script>
```

itemComponent.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" :value="item"/>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  props: {
    item: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```